# Override Date.prototype.toJSON for solving TimeZone problem in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have an angular 7 app. And I'm sending date to my server. But my time going to server 3 hour back because of time zone. **And I learnt that only way for solving this problem is writing** `Date.prototype.toJSON` . But, I don't know in angular, where should I write below code and how? (Forexample index.html, app.module.ts, ...) I wrote my stackblitz example at below.

```
Date.prototype.toJSON = function(key){
    //This code return me as string like "25.02.0219 19:48:52"
    return this.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + this.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1qu78p)

Comment: Why not just send an UTC or ISO date instead ? They contain the timezone and can  be used by most languages.

Comment: `And I learnt that only way for solving this problem is writing Date.prototype.toJSON`??? Surely not

Comment: I tried. But, my C# service always getting my value as 3 hour back. I create new C# application and new angular app. And I didn't do any additional configuration. But result not changed. Also client and server is same. It's my computer. @trichetriche

Comment: Please provide the UTC and ISO dates you're sending. I'm not sure you understand what they are ...

Comment: you can override the Date prototype in your main module. please check answer for detail

Comment: I wrote only to my client `this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/api/values', { birthdate: new Date() }).subscribe(result => { });` and I wrote only `[HttpPost] public void Post([FromBody] MyObject value){}         public class MyObject { public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; } }` . And I didn't wrote any configuration and everything is default and new empty project. But I take 3 hour back in my server @trichetriche

Comment: Yes @bambam . I tried all soluitions for a week. But only `Date.prototype.toJSON` worked perfectly. And this way is more generic. If you know another way, you explain please. You can see stackblitz in TheParam's answer

Comment: So yes, you're not sending Iso or utc dates hence you issue. Anyway, even though it's a very bad practice, your issue seems resolved, so see you around!

Comment: It’s either a misconfigured server, c program or just a matter of the correct parsing method. The answer you accepted is a hack and will fail depending on user location (amongst other reasons).

Comment: What can be the reason of my incorrect date ? @trichetriche . Am I doing somehing wrong? Because, everything is default and new project. I think  `Date.prototype.toJSON` is tricky way. And I hate tricky way. But, I couldn't find any other way.

Comment: I create empty C# solution and I create empty angular project by angular CLI. I didn't do any configuration. And I only send by `this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/api/values', { birthdate: new Date() }).subscribe(result => { });` But, I get 3 hour back date. I can't understand why? @bambam

Comment: Try with `new Date().toUTCString()` or `new Date().toISOString()`, which will return formatted dates containing the timezone and if I'm not mistaken the daytime savings too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @trichetriche . This can solve but I should write everywhere in all save methods in project. There will be hundreds of forms and thousands of date input. This means that I should write thousand times `new Date().toUTCString()` . If person in my team forget write this, then it's created incorrect data in my database. So, I'm looked for generic solution.

Comment: You're supposed to group your code. That means a date utils files, à service, an interceptor ... And you will also have to write `toJSON` everywhere, it's just the letters that change, making this argument irrelevant

Comment: You're right @trichetriche . Thanks a lot. You lighten me a lot. `Interceptor` will be better than `Date.prototype.toJSON` . Should I loop recursively all properties of posted object and then test it whether datetime or not? Or do you know any other easy way for doing this? For example, can I only change Date.prototype.toJSON in `Post` requests. Because maybe, looping recursively and test all properties of big `post` object whether datetime or not, will create **performance problem**.

Comment: You can check every key and if they contains "date" or time, you convert them. You can also use a specific header that you will remove before sending the request. You can finally use the interceptor in a single module, so that you know that it only applies to specific services

Comment: Thanks again @trichetriche . However it will be performance problem in big object, I will check every key and if they contains "date" or time in my interceptor.

Comment: Only on http requests, and that's only one possibility (and not a best practice). The header would be a good idea, the module specific interceptor too.

Comment: Yes, that's not best practice @trichetriche  But, completely automatic. In other two solution (header and specific interceptor) , I'm leaving the responsibility to the developer in my team. And if they write `save(studentObj)` instead of `save(studentObj, hasDateProperty)` by forgetting, then it will be created incorrect data in my database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can override Date prototype in the main entry point of your application in your case is AppModule.ts so it will be available to the whole application.

**App.module.ts**

```
export class AppModule {


  constructor() {
    this.overrideDate();
  }

  overrideDate() {
    Date.prototype.toJSON = function (key) {
      //This code return me as string like "25.02.0219 19:48:52"
      return this.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + this.toLocaleTimeString();
    }

  }
```

Now you can in your component it will be available.

```
  save() {

    console.log(this.myForm.value);
    this.http.post("localhost:5000",this.myForm.value).subscribe(result => {});
  }
```

**[Here is forked stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v1cymu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked perfectly. Finally I found solution. I think, this only solution for `Timezone` problem. Because, I tried every method for a week @TheParam

Comment: I'm glad I could help